# Powershell - Cannot remote install software (Cyberduck)

Tags: powershell, remote

On the remote machine, I copied the .exe file (from my source machine using Copy-Item command) to the temp folder first which was successful.  After that, I ran the following Powershell script on my machine, it ran quite fast but no message was displayed and the software was not installed on the remote machine.

$computerName = "LAPTOP"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
    C:\Temp\Cyberduck-Installer-6.9.4.30164.exe /silent}

On the remote machine, winRM services was started.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At first create a PoSH session by the example below:

```
$session = New-PSsession -ComputerName $computer -Credential (New-object PSCredential -ArgumentList ("login", ("password" |ConvertTo-secureString -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

and then Invoke-Command to the specified session as an example below:

```
Invoke-Command -session $session -Command {

script

}
```

and close PSS session

```
Remove-PSSession $session
```